# Run Computations on Dask Dataframe Without Collecting Results

Tags: python, dask

I would like to run computations on a partitioned dataframe but *not* collect results in the end. In the simplified example below, I'm doing a simple shuffle collecting rows with alike `shuffle_value`s. I then want to output something from each partition independently. The output of `ddf.compute()` collects the full Pandas dataframe which I don't want to do because A) I don't need the full dataframe in one place and B) it potentially won't fit in memory, besides. In small test cases something like below works for me, but it won't scale.

How do I trigger computation on each partition but *not* send any results to the calling process?

```py
ddf = dd.read_parquet(...)
ddf["shuffle_value"] = ddf.map_partitions(calc_shuffle_value,
                                     meta=("shuffle_value", "int64"))
ddf = ddf.shuffle(ddf.shuffle_value, ignore_index=True, npartitions=N)
ddf.map_partitions(output_func, meta=("unused_value", "int64"))
df = ddf.compute()
```

Thanks!

Comment: "I then want to output something from each partition independently" - such as?

Comment: Something calculated from each df; something from the shuffled/grouped partitions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, assuming that `output_func` mostly creates output by side-effects and doesn't return anything useful, there is no problem with executing your process with `.compute()`, as the dataframe returned will be tiny.

Assuming you are using distributed, other options include `.persist()`-ing the final dataframe, which will execute the process (asynchronously) and store the not-useful return values of each partition in the cluster but not gather them. You can then `del` to remove those data without collecting. The `client.submit` API would do a very similar thing.

```
df_out = ddf.persist()
# wait to finish - look at dashboard or use progress bar 
del df_out  # release
```

Comment: Seems to work, but it's a bit imperfect because it's hard for the script itself to know when the partitions are done being worked on.

Comment: You can check the futures_of df_out and use with distributed's wait function, if you like